# How to select a random member of a javascript array with n members such that every selection is as far as possible from the previous 3 selections?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

Suppose there is an array with 50 elements. Every time a random element is selected (all selected elements are still eligible for re-election in the subsequent iterations), is there a way to make sure that these new selections are as "far" as possible from the three items that were selected before it? Of course, this won't matter for the first three iterations.

By "far" I mean as distant (neighbour-wise) as possible from the previous 3 selections.

I am not sure if I make sense so feel free to correct any misconception I may display.

Comment: Do the 3 first selections have to be spread as far as possible too?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: After you randomly selected the 3 first values, you the rest numbers not to be random but to be the "farthest" number possible?

Comment: @Zenoo Ideally, yes. Thanks for response.

Comment: @NullPointer If I knew how to, I wouldn't be asking here. Thanks for response.

Comment: @Programmer Yes, it's not really "random" I get that but for the user it will appear to be somewhat random but distant. Thanks for response.

Comment: There's nothing random about this, then. The first 3 will always be the same, since they'll always have the same amount of numbers between them.

Comment: Are the values equally spaced?  In other words, if you have 50 values, do they correspond to the numbers 1-50 via a linear transformation?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you need to take the last 3 values, order them by value, get the max difference between two numbers, and return the middle number between them.

The main logic is something like that -

```
var lastThreeNumbers = [...];
lastThreeNumbers.sort();
var nextNumber;
if (lastThreeNumbers[1] - lastThreeNumbers[0] > lastThreeNumbers[2] - lastThreeNumbers[1]) {
   var diff = lastThreeNumbers[1] - lastThreeNumbers[0] / 2;
   nextNumber = lastThreeNumbers[0] + diff;
}
else {
   var diff = lastThreeNumbers[2] - lastThreeNumbers[1] / 2;
   nextNumber = lastThreeNumbers[1] + diff;
}
```

Edit:

On another thought, you need to take into consideration also 0 and 50, so you'll have an array of 5 values (the last 3 values, 0 and 50). But the main logic is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that I have tried to generate such an output:

```js
var arrayRandom = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"];
var firstHit = 0,
  secondHit = 1,
  thirdHit = 2,
  randomIndex;

function checkPrevious() {
  while (randomIndex == firstHit || randomIndex == secondHit || randomIndex == thirdHit) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayRandom.length);
  }
}

function generateInitialRandomIndex() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayRandom.length);
    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        checkPrevious();
        firstHit = randomIndex;
        alert(firstHit + ":" + arrayRandom[firstHit]);
        break;
      case 1:
        checkPrevious();
        secondHit = randomIndex;
        alert(secondHit + ":" + arrayRandom[secondHit]);
        break;
      case 2:
        checkPrevious();
        thirdHit = randomIndex;
        alert(thirdHit + ":" + arrayRandom[thirdHit]);
        break;
    }
  }
}

$("button.generate-random-index").click(function() {
  generateInitialRandomIndex();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="generate-random-index">
  Hit Me
</button>
```

In this algorithm I have taken the array index as inputs in 3 different variables, so that whenever a random index is generated, it can be compared with the previous hits. If it is same, then a new random index is generated, otherwise, it is selected as Output.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/thisisdg/ha45zykv/68/) is the link to my fiddle from where you can take reference for this code.

Hope this was helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Do it with ES6+ and arrow function